# Combination of CImg and fftw++ fails

Tags: c++, fftw, cimg

I want to do a fft in my c++ project, and show it afterwards as an image. In order to do the fft, I am using fftw++, and for displaying the image I wanted to use the CImg-library. Thus I started with the demo project from [here](http://fftwpp.sourceforge.net/example0.cc). When compiling it, everything works. As soon as I add the CImg-header, it fails with the error

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:18:12: error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope
   Complex *f=ComplexAlign(n);
```

My file looks like

```
#include "fftw++.h"
#include "CImg.h"
// Compile with:
// g++ -I .. -fopenmp example0.cc ../fftw++.cc -lfftw3 -lfftw3_omp

//using namespace std;
//using namespace utils;
//using namespace fftwpp;
//using namespace cimg_library;
int main()
{
  fftwpp::fftw::maxthreads=get_max_threads();

  std::cout << "1D complex to complex in-place FFT, not using the Array class"
       << std::endl;

  unsigned int n=4;
  Complex *f=utils::ComplexAlign(n);

  fftwpp::fft1d Forward(n,-1);
  fftwpp::fft1d Backward(n,1);

  for(unsigned int i=0; i < n; i++) f[i]=i;

  std::cout << "\ninput:" << std::endl;
  for(unsigned int i=0; i < n; i++) std::cout << f[i] << std::endl;

  Forward.fft(f);

  std::cout << "\noutput:" << std::endl;
  for(unsigned int i=0; i < n; i++) std::cout << f[i] << std::endl;

  Backward.fftNormalized(f);

  std::cout << "\ntransformed back:" << std::endl;
  for(unsigned int i=0; i < n; i++) std::cout << f[i] << std::endl;

  utils::deleteAlign(f);
}
```

and is compiled with

```
g++ -I .. -fopenmp test.cpp ../fftw++.cc -lfftw3 -lfftw3_omp
```

My g++ version is 4.8.5. Adding the `Complex.h`-header does not help either. What can I do in order to combine both libraries?

Edit: Further research shows that using the C-library `complex.h` and `CImg.h` results in a lot of compilation problems, combining the library `Complex.h` from the `fftw++`-package results also in errors, only the `complex`-include from C++ can be used together with the `CImg.h`-include file. Reason: Unknown till now.

Comment: Get rid of all that heavy-handed use of `using namespace ...` for a start...

Comment: @PaulR: Fixed, I left it in before in order to stay as close to the original as possible. Still the same problem

Comment: My guess would be that `Complex` is defined in more than one place, but I'm not *au fait* with CImg or fftw++.

Comment: @PaulR: `CImg` does not like the complex-definition from `fftw`, but atm I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: You probably need to put a simple C++ wrapper around CImg and put it in its own namespace.

Comment: @PaulR: Solved it, see answer.

Comment: Well done - that is pretty much what I meant in the comment above about a wrapper around CImg (except you didn't seem to need to bother with a namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution (even if it is not perfect) is, that I created a second cpp-file:
second.cpp:

```
#include "CImg.h"
//Code for images
void example(void){
}
```

and an include-file for that:
second.h:

```
#ifndef SECOND_H
#define SECOND_H

void example(void);


#endif /* SECOND_H */
```

If I only include that include file instead of `CImg.h`, I can use both `fftw++` and `CImg`.